# Buildroot includes host path in python libs and other makefiles in target image - pip install failing

Tags: buildroot

I did a buildroot (2022.08.1) make of a raspberrypi3_defconfig with some changes (include python3, kdb, wpa_supplicant, iwd and some others).
My issue is that if I then run for example `pip install python-lirc` on the target raspberrypi3, I get an error that some files are missing and `setup.py` cannot complete.

The issue is that apparently my host system (WSL2 on Win11) paths are somehow included in the target build, as I see the file system structure of my host in the output errors.
For example `/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/share/gcc-10.3.1/python`
Then I searched for that string `/mnt/Kali` in all files inside the `sdcard.img` image which I just unpacked with 7z and get following result:

```
D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\lib\libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py (2 Treffer)
    Zeile 22: pythondir = '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/share/gcc-10.3.1/python'
    Zeile 23: libdir = "/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/lib"
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\bin\irdb-get (1 Treffer)
    Zeile   1: #!/usr/bin/env /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/python
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\bin\irtext2udp (1 Treffer)
    Zeile  1: #!/usr/bin/env /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/python
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\bin\lirc-init-db (1 Treffer)
    Zeile  1: #!/usr/bin/env /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/python
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\bin\pronto2lirc (1 Treffer)
    Zeile   1: #!/usr/bin/env /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/python
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\lib\libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py (2 Treffer)
    Zeile 22: pythondir = '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/share/gcc-10.3.1/python'
    Zeile 23: libdir = "/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/lib"
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\lib\python3.10\config-3.10-arm-linux-gnueabihf\Makefile (12 Treffer)
    Zeile   33: abs_srcdir= /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7
    Zeile   34: abs_builddir=   /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7
    Zeile   37: CC=     /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
    Zeile   38: CXX=        /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++
    Zeile   41: AR=     /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar
    Zeile   42: READELF=    /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-readelf
    Zeile  205: OPENSSL_INCLUDES=-I/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include
    Zeile  207: OPENSSL_LDFLAGS=-L/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib
    Zeile  220: CONFIG_ARGS=     '--target=arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf' '--host=arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf' '--build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--program-prefix=' '--disable-gtk-doc' '--disable-gtk-doc-html' '--disable-doc' '--disable-docs' '--disable-documentation' '--with-xmlto=no' '--with-fop=no' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-ipv6' '--disable-nls' '--disable-static' '--enable-shared' '--disable-lib2to3' '--disable-berkeleydb' '--disable-readline' '--disable-curses' '--with-libmpdec=none' '--with-expat=system' '--disable-sqlite3' '--with-openssl=/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr' '--disable-codecs-cjk' '--disable-uuid' '--disable-bzip2' '--disable-xz' '--disable-ossaudiodev' '--without-ensurepip' '--without-cxx-main' '--with-system-ffi' '--disable-pydoc' '--disable-test-modules' '--disable-tk' '--disable-nis' '--disable-idle3' '--disable-pyc-build' 'build_alias=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf' 'target_alias=arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf' 'CC=/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' 'CFLAGS=-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' 'LDFLAGS=' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' 'CPP=/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-cpp' 'PKG_CONFIG=/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/pkg-config'
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\lib\python3.10\lib-dynload\array.cpython-310-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so (1 Treffer)
    Zeile 225: 
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\lib\python3.10\lib-dynload\pyexpat.cpython-310-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so (1 Treffer)
    Zeile 197: 
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\lib\python3.10\lib-dynload\_asyncio.cpython-310-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so (1 Treffer)
    Zeile 330: 
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\lib\python3.10\lib-dynload\_sha3.cpython-310-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so (1 Treffer)
    Zeile 149: 
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\lib\python3.10\lib-dynload\_ssl.cpython-310-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so (1 Treffer)
    Zeile 641: 
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\lib\python3.10\site-packages\lirc-setup\lirc-setup (1 Treffer)
    Zeile  1: #!/usr/bin/env /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/python
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\lib\python3.10\_sysconfigdata__linux_arm-linux-gnueabihf.py (21 Treffer)
    Zeile  10:  'AR': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar',
    Zeile  18:  'BLDSHARED': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc '
    Zeile  24:  'CC': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc',
    Zeile  59:                 "'--with-openssl=/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr' "
    Zeile  68:                 "'CC=/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' "
    Zeile  73:                 "'CPP=/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-cpp' "
    Zeile  74:                 "'PKG_CONFIG=/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/pkg-config'",
    Zeile  78:  'COVERAGE_INFO': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7/coverage.info',
    Zeile  79:  'COVERAGE_REPORT': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7/lcov-report',
    Zeile  84:  'CXX': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++',
    Zeile 574:  'LDCXXSHARED': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ '
    Zeile 580:  'LDSHARED': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc '
    Zeile 599:  'LINKCC': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc',
    Zeile 612:  'MAINCC': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc',
    Zeile 642:  'OPENSSL_INCLUDES': '-I/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include',
    Zeile 643:  'OPENSSL_LDFLAGS': '-L/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib',
    Zeile 675:  'PYTHON_FOR_BUILD': '_PYTHON_PROJECT_BASE=/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7 '
    Zeile 678:                      '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7/`cat '
    Zeile 740:  'READELF': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-readelf',
    Zeile 814:  'abs_builddir': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7',
    Zeile 815:  'abs_srcdir': '/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7',
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\lib\python3.10\__pycache__\_sysconfigdata__linux_arm-linux-gnueabihf.cpython-310.pyc (17 Treffer)
    Zeile  12: AIX_BUILDDATEZAIX_GENUINE_CPLUSPLUSZALIGNOF_LONGé
    Zeile  15: BLDLIBRARYz-L. -lpython3.10Z    BLDSHAREDzL/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -sharedZBUILDEXEZBUILDPYTHONZpythonZBUILD_GNU_TYPEzx86_64-pc-linux-gnuZBYTESTR_DEPSú\ZCCzD/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gccZCCSHAREDz-fPICZCFLAGSz–-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g  -O3 -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1ZCFLAGSFORSHAREDZCFLAGS_ALIASINGZ
    Zeile  16: CFLAGS_NODISTZCONFIGFILESz?configure configure.ac acconfig.h pyconfig.h.in Makefile.pre.inZCONFIGURE_CFLAGSz]-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os -g0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1ZCONFIGURE_CFLAGS_NODISTz§-std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fvisibility=hiddenZCONFIGURE_CPPFLAGSz@-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64ZCONFIGURE_LDFLAGSZCONFIGURE_LDFLAGS_NODISTZCONFIG_ARGSaÒ
    Zeile  18: COVERAGE_INFOzA/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7/coverage.infoZCOVERAGE_REPORTz?/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7/lcov-reportZCOVERAGE_REPORT_OPTIONSz2--no-branch-coverage --title "CPython lcov report"ZCPPFLAGSzP-I. -I./Include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64ZCXXzD/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ZDESTDIRSzA/usr /usr/lib /usr/lib/python3.10 /usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynloadZDESTLIBZDESTPATHZ
    Zeile 107: INSTSONAMEzlibpython3.10.so.1.0ZIO_HzModules/_io/_iomodule.hZIO_OBJSZLDCXXSHAREDzL/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -sharedZLDFLAGSZLDFLAGS_NODISTZ    LDLIBRARYzlibpython3.10.soZLDLIBRARYDIRZLDSHAREDZ    LDVERSIONz3.10ZLIBCZLIBDESTZLIBDIRz/usr/libZLIBFFI_INCLUDEDIRZLIBMz-lmZ LIBOBJDIRzPython/ZLIBOBJSZLIBPCz/usr/lib/pkgconfigZLIBPLz3/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-arm-linux-gnueabihfZ LIBPYTHONZLIBRARYzlibpython3.10.aZLIBRARY_DEPSz.libpython3.10.a libpython3.10.so libpython3.soZLIBRARY_OBJSZLIBRARY_OBJS_OMIT_FROZENZLIBSz,-lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lpthread -lutil -lmZ
    Zeile 110: LLVM_PROF_ERRZLLVM_PROF_FILEZLLVM_PROF_MERGERÚtrueZLNZlnZLOCALMODLIBSZMACHDEPZlinuxZMACHDEP_OBJSZMACHDESTLIBZMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGETZMAINCCZMAJOR_IN_MKDEVZMAJOR_IN_SYSMACROSZ    MAKESETUPz./Modules/makesetupZMANDIRz/usr/share/manZMKDIR_Pz/usr/bin/mkdir -pZMODBUILT_NAMESzÇposix  errno  pwd  _sre  _codecs  _weakref  _functools  _operator  _collections  _abc  itertools  atexit  _signal  _stat  time  _thread  _locale  _io  faulthandler  _tracemalloc  _symtable  xxsubtypeZMODDISABLED_NAMESZMODLIBSZMODOBJSab
    Zeile 117: PYTHONPATHZPYTHON_FOR_BUILDaI
    Zeile 120: QUICKTESTOPTSz)-x test_subprocess test_io test_lib2to3 \ZREADELFzH/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-readelfZ RESSRCDIRzMac/Resources/frameworkZ
    Zeile 138: XMLLIBSUBDIRSz)xml xml/dom xml/etree xml/parsers xml/saxZabs_builddirz3/mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/build/python3-3.10.7Z
  D:\OutputBuildroot\sdcard\1\usr\sbin\lircd-setup (1 Treffer)
    Zeile  1: #!/usr/bin/env /mnt/wsl/Kali/buildroot/output/host/bin/python
```

What could be the bug that those paths are included in my build?